# is there any way for making an image circular in the center of splash screen?

Tags: flutter, splash-screen, android-splashscreen

In my flutter app I created a splash screen.I have one problem.I can not make center image circular image.What shoudld I write instead of center here android:gravity="center" ?
I share the view of my splash screen.You will understand which image I want to make circular.

[image: screenshoot of splash screen]

I tried to write fill,center-fill instead of center,but none of them helped...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you would like your splash image to be circular.  If that is the case, you should crop the circle shape in the PNG source, leaving the corners cutouts as transparent sections.  Then, use `flutter_native_splash` to update the image with your new cropped circular image.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [CircleAvatar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircleAvatar-class.html) od [ClipOval](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipOval-class.html)
both of them would achive that easily

Comment: I used flutter_native_splash package for creating splash screen.That is why I have not written in inside of scaffold widget. I need to add something to instead of center here android:gravity="center" inside of xml document

Comment: I meant as a replacement for the splash package

Answer (score 0):

you can use `CircleAvatar` class

If the avatar is to have an image, the image should be specified in the backgroundImage property:

```
CircleAvatar(
  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(userAvatarUrl),
)
```

also you can refer https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircleAvatar-class.html#material.CircleAvatar.1